# how to check mysql id row number with php?

Tags: php, mysql

how to check mysql id row number with php? my code not works

```
$id = '$url_id';
$con=mysqli_connect("DBHOST","DBUSER","DBPASS","DBNAME");
$sqlCheckRow = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM gagzavnili WHERE id=".$url_id." " ) or die ( mysql_error() );
$rowCounted = mysql_num_rows( $sqlCheckRow );
if ( $rowCounted == '50' ) @header("location:error8.php");
```

Comment: You're mixing MySQL APIs by the way. They do **not** mix.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: You seem to be mixing MySQLi and MySQL. You should just use MySQLi as MySQL is depreciated

Comment: Read up => http://www.mdloring.com/2013/php/php-mysqli-query-beginner/ and http://codular.com/php-mysqli and http://webdevtuts.co.uk/simple-mysqli-tutorial/

Comment: Also - `mysql_num_rows` returns the number of rows from your SELECT. Do you have 50 rows with that ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute the following SQL statement, it should do the trick:

```
$sqlCheckRow = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gagzavnili WHERE id=$url_id" ) or die
(mysql_error() );
```

Comment: error

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1**